# Looking for MS Lightswitch alternative to create a mid-size CRM

Tags: .net, crm

Lightswitch seems to be a good solution but the HTML UI is very poor, and Silverlight is limiting.

I am looking in general for a good rapid framework in .NET to create a mid-size CRM (data centric application).

**Must Have:**

- Custom entities with many to one relations
- Custom fields (text, combo, relation picker, date)
- File uploads
- Custom views for each entity with custom query
- User management (roles & permissions)
- HTML on the client side (not Flash or Silverlight)

**Nice to have:**

- My custom fields
- Reporting
- Custom view per user role / user group / user
- Multi device HTML client
- Custom workflow

There are 2 solution that I know which are similar, but:

- http://www.vidyano.com/ is too expensive
- http://www.coevery.com the documentation is in Chinese

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically, name your requirements explicitly (instead of just writing "similar to"): what are must-haves, what nice-to-haves? People not knowing "Vidyano" might still know a perfect match for your case ;)

Comment: Vidiano is free now, but their blog wasn't updated for 4 years

Answer (score 1):

As it was discussed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lightswitch/2014/12/05/where-we-are-and-the-road-ahead/) there are just a few proper alternatives - non .NET. I went for the [CUBA Platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/) framework, because I have almost the same Must Have and Should Have lists and CUBA covered all the requrements. It has strong built in modules for Reproting, BPM and Charting - that was a determinative for me.

As for changing stack, CUBA Studio (specialized IDE) allowed me to get used to the framework quite shortly, so it wasn't that hard to move from MS to Java.

Answer (score 1):

One year ago we launched a product called Radzen which allows rapid web application development with ASP.NET Core and Angular. I has been [received well](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4304/Radzen-ndash-The-New-LightSwitch.aspx) by the LightSwitch community and I welcome everyone to try it. One can even use [their existing LightSwitch service](https://www.radzen.com/documentation/migrating-from-lightswitch/)!